# "/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcudart"

Tags: compiling, make, cuda, opencv

I am newbie to Ubuntu and using Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit. I want to `make` a project that uses `cuda` and `opencv` I got the following error when running `cmake . && make`

```
Linking CXX executable ground_estimation
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcudart
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [ground_estimation] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/ground_estimation.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

This is the output of `ld -lcudart --verbose`

```
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64/libcudart.so failed
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64/libcudart.a failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudart.so failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudart.a failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib64/libcudart.so failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib64/libcudart.a failed
attempt to open //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudart.so failed
attempt to open //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudart.a failed
attempt to open //lib64/libcudart.so failed
attempt to open //lib64/libcudart.a failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudart.so failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudart.a failed
attempt to open //usr/lib64/libcudart.so failed
attempt to open //usr/lib64/libcudart.a failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/libcudart.so failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/libcudart.a failed
attempt to open //lib/libcudart.so failed
attempt to open //lib/libcudart.a failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/libcudart.so failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/libcudart.a failed
```

`libcudart` exist in `/usr/local/cuda/lib64` and I also added to Library Path:

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/lib/nvidia-current:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/lib:
```

This is the output of `ls /usr/local/cuda/lib64`:

```
libcublas_device.a   libcufftw.so.6.0.37    libnppi.so.6.0
libcublas.so         libcuinj64.so          libnppi.so.6.0.37
libcublas.so.6.0     libcuinj64.so.6.0      libnpps.so
libcublas.so.6.0.37  libcuinj64.so.6.0.37   libnpps.so.6.0
libcudadevrt.a       libcurand.so           libnpps.so.6.0.37
libcudart.so         libcurand.so.6.0       libnvblas.so
libcudart.so.6.0     libcurand.so.6.0.37    libnvblas.so.6.0
libcudart.so.6.0.37  libcusparse.so         libnvblas.so.6.0.37
libcudart_static.a   libcusparse.so.6.0     libnvToolsExt.so
libcufft.so          libcusparse.so.6.0.37  libnvToolsExt.so.1
libcufft.so.6.0      libnppc.so             libnvToolsExt.so.1.0.0
libcufft.so.6.0.37   libnppc.so.6.0         libOpenCL.so
libcufftw.so         libnppc.so.6.0.37      libOpenCL.so.1
libcufftw.so.6.0     libnppi.so
```

What should I do that `ld` search in `/usr/local/cuda/lib64` path to find `libcudart`?

Comment: can you please `ls /usr/local/cuda/lib64`?

Comment: The same question happened to me too. Reference from the article: 
[Debian compiling OpenCV examples with IPP: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibsvml.so collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24234961/debian-compiling-opencv-examples-with-ipp-usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-llibsvml-so/26941723?noredirect=1#comment42427489_26941723

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Make a symbolic link to `libcuda` where `ld` is searching it.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so /usr/lib/libcudart.so
```

Comment: Is there a way to symlink the whole /lib folder without symlinking every individual file?

Answer (score 15):

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is used to modify the behaviour of the `ldconfig` and related tools when looking for the libraries, at execution time.

The `ld` linker tool doesn't use this variable. If you want to use a library located in a non-standard directory, you have to use the `-L` parameter of the command, like this :

```
ld -lcuda -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64
```

If you have downloaded and existing project and doesn't know how to modify the existing Makefile(s) without breaking the whole compilation, you can run **make** the following way :

```
export LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64
make
```

The variable LDFLAGS (which may be also defined into the Makefile), is used to pass specific arguments to the linker (`ld`) when launched by the compilation intructions.

Comment: I got `ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; not setting start address` when run `ld -lcuda -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64`

Comment: @Arash: did you install the version of libcuda requested by the porject you try to compile ?

Comment: same problem as @Arash and yes I have the correct version of libcuda

Answer (score 2):

You can make links instead of adding the paths:

```
ln -s /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so /usr/local/lib/
ln -s /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart.a /usr/local/lib/
```

Comment: i do not have /usr/local/lib64/ ,i have /usr/local/lib/

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this! Go to your makefile and change

```
/usr/local/cuda/
```

to

```
/usr/local/cuda-7.0
```

(if that's what you got)

It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Solved

```
git clone https://github.com/inducer/pycuda.git
cd pycuda
sudo configure --cuda-root=/usr/lib/cuda-10.1

sudo ln -s /usr/lib/cuda-10.1/targets/x86_64-linux/include src/cpp/
```

OR
copy all header files from /usr/lib/cuda-10.1/targets/x86_64-linux/include to /src/cpp/

It worked for me on Pop-OS 19.10